# Dynamically wrap a js string by span tags which can be dangerously rendered in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a string and I would like to add span tags to the alphabets alone with an aria-label tag. The end result will be dangerously rendered in React. Please advice. This is what I have.

```js
const str = `D = (C - B) / B`;

const addAriaLabels = (str) => {
  function alphaOnly(a) {
    var b = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'z') b += a[i];
    }
    return b;
  }
  return alphaOnly(str).split('').map(item => `<span aria-label=\'column ${item}\'>${item}</span>`).join('')
}

console.log(addAriaLabels(str))
```

Expected Output:

`<span aria-label='column D'>D</span> = (<span aria-label='column C'>C</span> - <span aria-label='column B'>B</span>) / <span aria-label='column B'>B</span>`

I am not sure on how to add back the symbols itself.

Example:

If string is A, result should be `<span aria-label="column A">A</span>`.

If string is D = (C - B) / B, result should be
`<span aria-label='column D'>D</span> = (<span aria-label='column C'>C</span> - <span aria-label='column B'>B</span>) / <span aria-label='column B'>B</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for this.

Explanation:

- The regex `/([a-z]+)/i` matches all substrings of 1 or more Latin alphabet letters, case insensitive.
- `String#split` with a regex capturing group (`/(...)/`) includes the captured text in the results at odd-numbered indexes. For example, `'baba'.split(/(b)/)` gives you `["", "b", "a", "b", "a"]`.

  Once you have these results, you can map the captured, odd-indexed results (`idx % 2`) to `span` elements and the even ones to `React.Fragment`s.

`addAriaLabels` now returns an array of React components, which can be rendered directly inside a parent.

```js
const addAriaLabels = str =>
  str.split(/([a-z]+)/i)
    .map((substr, idx) => idx % 2
      ? <span key={idx} aria-label={`column ${substr}`}>{substr}</span>
      : <React.Fragment key={idx}>{substr}</React.Fragment>)

const Parent = () => {
  const str = `D = (C - B) / B`

  return (
    <>
      {addAriaLabels(str)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the string characters if the current character is an alphabet add that tags to it then assign it to already defined string else just assign the character :

```js
const originalStr = `D = (C - B) / B`

function addAriaLabels(str) {
  let newStr = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].match(/[A-Z]/g) && str[i].match(/[A-Z]/g).length > 0) {
      newStr += `<span aria-label=\'column ${str[i]}\'>${str[i]}</span>`
    } else {
      newStr += str[i]
    }

  }

  return newStr;
}

console.log(addAriaLabels(originalStr))
```